# Monthly Moving Average SQL

Tags: postgresql, moving-average

I have a postgreSQL table with columns:

1. year [integer 1960-2014]
2. month [integer 1-12]   and
3. a value column. [double precision]

year and month are separate columns due to the input data I don't have control over. I could merge them into a datetime column.

Now I would like to calculate the 10 year moving average. The 10Y moving average for Jan 1969 should be AVG( Jan 1960, Jan 1961 .. Jan 1969) etc.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT year,month, value,
    AVG(value)
        OVER(ORDER BY year ROWS BETWEEN 9 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as ma10_value
FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Partition` explained [here](https://compose.com/articles/metrics-maven-window-frames-in-postgresql/)

```
SELECT value, year, month,
  SUM(value)
    OVER(PARTITION BY month ORDER BY year ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as ma2_value
FROM test01
```

[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f4746/2)